# contacts interception

Tags: android, contacts

is there any posibilty to intercept the contact.
if user add,delete and update any contact system notify that changes occur in the contact.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a data observer on the relevant ContactsContract content provider.

Comment: i try to use observer on both Contacts.CONTENT_URI and People.CONTENT_URI. on change its also calling onChange(boolean selfChange) but more than 1 times. Calling more than 1 times making problem for me. any suggestion plz