# How does one get the Contact change notification with Contact id?

Tags: android

I m developing application in which i want to get the notification for contact change with ID.

Comment: You may want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672809/contacts-interception)

Comment: but this is not giving changed contact id..

Comment: Yeah ... thats not possible as far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the notification is very simple. i also searched a lot for the same stuff. I could not find any solution. Content observer notifies that there is a change in your contact. You have to use some contact id comparison technique to find out the proper solution.
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Use ContentObserver.

```
@Override
public void onChange (boolean selfChange)
{
    this.onChange(selfChange, null);
}

@Override
public void onChange (boolean selfChange,Uri uri)
{
    Cursor cursor = mCntxt.getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null,null,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP + " Desc");
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String id = cursor.getString(
            cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String name = cursor.getString(
            cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    Log.w("Contact ID", id);
    Log.w("Person Name",name);
   }
}
```

Hope it helps....

Answer (score 0):

The `ContentObserver` class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html is meant for this job, but does not give you change of ID, only the total change.

You are stuck by implementing that a pre-handler vs post-handler to see what changed yourself.

Comment: my concern is this will give any change happen.. i want the specific id. this i have implemented already...